# Storyboard text showing up in UI

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to implement a storyboard in the UI through XAML. For some reason it is displaying on the screen as one of the items (understandable given it is in the panorama). However, no matter where I move it, it is considered invalid and VS goes out on the town highlighting it as invalid.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama Title="The Journey" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-1.492,2.985,0.001" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Loaded="Panorama_Loaded_1">
        <phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.03"/>
        </phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Journey Name" Name="journeyName"/>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="journeyName"
                            From="Blue"
                            To="White"
                            Duration="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

as a result I get something like

```
System.Windows.Media.Animation.BeginAnimation
```

as text for one of the items.

Any ideas? I am very new to XAML so I am not very familiar with its structuring rules. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't take the time to test your stuff, but from the looks of it you've got a couple issues there. For starters there's a broken `</Grid>` end tag there in the center. Second is you need to declare your storyboard's as a resource for whatever you're working with. You'll also need a way to invoke it via some event (will leave that for you to decide) and you're not targeting a property on the object you wish to interact with. So to give you a beginning idea where you're off;

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Grid.Resources>
       <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="journeyName"
                            <!-- Not sure what property it is you're 
                                 trying to interact with here, replace
                                 "Property" with whatever it is... -->
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Property"
                            From="Blue"
                            To="White"
                            Duration="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </Grid.Resources>
    <phone:Panorama Title="The Journey" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-1.492,2.985,0.001" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Loaded="Panorama_Loaded_1">
        <phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.03"/>
        </phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Journey Name" Name="journeyName"/>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="">
        </phone:PanoramaItem>       
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

However I might also suggest a quick trip to the google machine and doing a quick tutorial search to learn some of the [basics](https://www.google.com/search?q=xaml%20storyboard%20animation%20tutorial). Also, Expression Blend makes any sort of storyboard work a lot easier and more efficient so its worth looking in to also. Hope this helps, cheers!